.NET Exception serialization no longer working without legacy pattern, Newtonsoft.Json - intentional?
This question refers to code which still uses Newtonsoft.Json. Following tests also made use of System.Text.Json.
I finally wanted to remove the obsolete pattern, with [SerializableAttribute], protected ctor and GetObjectData(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext) from my exceptions.
Now serializers, both System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer and Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert don't deserialize the exception properly:
although not relying on old IFormatter (really not?), [edit] Newtonsoft.Json serialized and deserialized exceptions implementing the old pattern. Now, deserializing not even reproduces the original exception message, but a new message is created when deserializing SomeIdNotFoundException:

Exception of type '....SomeIdNotFoundException' was thrown.

I see that exception classes, both custom and common .NET types, including the basic System.Exception, don't fit the usual requirements for (de)serialization, by having private/protected and read-only members, but is it intentional to lose all exception content, unless using special configurations?
Edit: Example
With legacy serialization
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[Serializable]
public class SomeIdNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public SomeIdNotFoundException()
    { }

    public SomeIdNotFoundException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }

    public SomeIdNotFoundException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    { }

    protected SomeIdNotFoundException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    { }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ExceptionSerializationTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeIdNotFoundException_Serialization_RoundTrip()
    {
        var expectedMessage = "Some ID not found.";
        var originalException = new SomeIdNotFoundException(expectedMessage);
        //var originalException = Assert.ThrowsException<SomeIdNotFoundException>(
        //    () => throw new SomeIdNotFoundException(expectedMessage));

        var deserializedException = SerializeAndDeserialize(originalException);

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessage, deserializedException.Message);
    }

    private static SomeIdNotFoundException SerializeAndDeserialize(SomeIdNotFoundException exceptionToSerialize)
    {
        //var serializedException = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(exceptionToSerialize);
        //return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeIdNotFoundException>(serializedException)!;
        var serializedException = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exceptionToSerialize);
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeIdNotFoundException>(serializedException)!;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new ExceptionSerializationTests()
            .SomeIdNotFoundException_Serialization_RoundTrip();
    }
}

Without legacy serialization
Exception class only.
// no Serializable attribute
public class SomeIdNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public SomeIdNotFoundException()
    { }

    public SomeIdNotFoundException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }

    public SomeIdNotFoundException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    { }
}

Direct exception instantiation (no throw)
With legacy pattern disabled
Deserialization with both, System and Newtonsoft, serializers generates a new exception message of this kind:

Exception of type '[namespace].SomeIdNotFoundException' was thrown.

With legacy pattern still available

System.Text.Json behaves like without legacy pattern, creating a deserialized exception with a new exception message.
Newtonsoft.Json performs a full deserialization of the method, preserving the original message.

Thrown exception
Throwing the exception, like in the commented-out part with Assert.ThrowsException<SomeIdNotFoundException>(...). Then, deserialization never works with System.Text.Json, no matter if the legacy pattern is implemented.
Error messages for thrown exception with System.Text.Json:

System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Reflection.MethodBase' instances is not supported. Path: $.TargetSite. --->
System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Reflection.MethodBase' instances is not supported.

Newtonsoft.Json has no problem with thrown exceptions, as long as the legacy pattern is available.

I don't think System.Text.Json ever serialized exceptions or supported ISerializable out of the box, see Why does System.Text.Json throw a NotSupportedException for System.IntPtr when I'm not using System.IntPtr?.  If you are seeing differences in the behavior of STJ with respect to exceptions, might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

On the other hand, Newtonsoft.Json and the data contract serializers honor ISerializable, see Serialization Guide: ISerializable.  If you remove [SerializableAttribute] and/or ISerializable from your types, serialization using Newtonsoft or the data contract serializers will break.  So that would be expected behavior as per the Newtonsoft documentation.

Finally, the format for questions here is one per post so you might want to split your post into two questions, one for System.Text.Json and one for Json.NET, and add a [mcve] for each.

As mentioned before, serialization of exceptions has never been supported by System.Text.Json.  See Why does System.Text.Json throw a NotSupportedException for System.IntPtr when I'm not using System.IntPtr?.  You have to write your own converter, see this answer by Uttam Ughareja for an example.

Using Json.NET I can't reproduce your problem in .NET 9 using the SomeIdNotFoundException and test method in your question.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/zqOkER.  Please share a [mcve].

@dbc I added some examples, showing the differences, also between System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json. Since I still have Newtonsoft in many places, the unexpected failure was the starting point, and I tried also with the newer System.Text.Json implementation.

I copied your example code + exception into a fiddle and Json.NET worked fine, there was no probem.  Can you share a [mcve] showing Json.NET failing "With legacy pattern disabled" please?

The IntPtr problem in the other post seems to be similar to the Reflection error with MethodBase I am getting, only referring to different types (which are not normally serializable).

They are the same problem, it's just that System.Text.Json has changed dramatically from release to release so throws a slightly different error message in .NET 9 than in .NET 8.  Also you may be getting a different error message because you never threw and caught your  exception so certain fields are still null.  (It would really help if you could separate your issues with different serializers into different questions, it's getting hard to keep track of your problems.)

Using your "Without legacy serialization" version of SomeIdNotFoundException I get a completely different exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: ISerializable type 'SomeIdNotFoundException' does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present., see https://dotnetfiddle.net/563Eko. That's because Newtonsoft supports exception serialization via the ISerializable pattern, if you remove the required methods it breaks.  So that error is intentional.

@dbc You probably still had the [Serializable] attribute on the exception class; when I restored it, I got the same, ctor-related error. When removing it, it's like in my examples, both NET8 and 9.

OK, Json.NET demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1dxd1k.  Anyway, for Newtonsoft the answer to your question is Yes this is intentional.  Newtonsoft is designed to serialize exceptions via the ISerializable pattern, if you remove it then exceptions cannot be round-tripped successfully, e.g. because Exception.Message is read-only.  And System.Text.Json never round-tripped exceptions at all so no change there either way.

@dbc For the minimum runnable, I edited my code, added test class and Main() method, so it can be run without test environment. I also adapted your example in dotnetfiddle, to run without separate Program class, similar to my code here. I expected test methods to be easiest to run, without adding full program code.

Regarding System.Text.Json, see this comment by a MSFT employee to System.Text.Json - can't serialize exception #43026: Currently, .NET provides no way to deserialize exceptions without using the ISerializable pattern from BinaryFormatter... Recommendation is to use a custom converter ... for exception serialization, however we recommend against writing converters that support exception deserialization..

The same comment refers to issue Consider allowing Exception instances to be serialized without requiring BinaryFormatter #43482 which is still open.

I consider the question answered, not as easy as I expected, but interesting to dive into the different JSON serializers. For me, SonarQube code checks still complain about the legacy pattern not implemented (S3925), when I leave it out, and in some cases, we may have to serialize exceptions.

Answering my own question:

Newtonsoft.Json supports the legacy serialization pattern for exceptions.
System.Text.Json never supported exception serialization by default.

Without the legacy pattern, or specific coding, none of these JSON serializations support exception serialization.
See also links from @dbc in the comments under the question!
